# How do I update the position of a jQuery Mobile global popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, popup, position

I have a jQuery Mobile global popup, whose contents are generated dynamically. So by default it's empty.

I'm listening for the [`beforeposition`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#event-beforeposition) event to capture the popup being opened. Then I load a config file/content file, generate the content and append it to the popup.

However by the time I'm appending, JQM is already done calculating the position of the popup so it will be misplaced on the screen.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
$(document).find("#global-popup")
    .on("popupbeforeposition", function (e) {
    factory.util.generatePopupContents(app.generateActionObject(e));
});


factory.util.generatePopupContents = function (obj) {
    var i, j, promises, fragment, popup, reference, state;

    popup = obj.gadget,
    reference = popup.getAttribute("data-reference"),
    state = popup.getAttribute("data-state");

    // don't reload if same popup is opened
    if (state !== reference) {
        if (reference === null) {
            util.errorHandler({
                "error": "Global Bindings: No handler for popup"
            });
        } else {
            popup.setAttribute("data-state", reference);
            popup.setAttribute("data-reference", reference);
            promises = [];

            // fetch content > THIS WILL LOAD A JSON DICT
            app.fetchConfiguration({
                "storage": app.default_dict.storage_dict.settings,
                    "file": app.default_dict.storage_dict.gadgets,
                    "attachment": reference,
                    "pass": undefined
            })
                .then(function (reply) {
                obj.gadget.setAttribute("data-reference", reference);
                // loop children in JSON dict
                if (reply.children) {
                    for (i = 0; i < reply.children.length; i += 1) {
                        promises[i] = app.setContent(reply.children[i], {}, false);
                    }
                }
                return RSVP.all(promises)
            })
                .then(function (content) {
                // create a fragment and append generated content
                fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
                for (j = 0; j < content.length; j += 1) {
                    fragment.appendChild(content[j]);
                }

                // translate fragment if needed
                if (i18n) {
                    map.actions.translateNodeList(fragment);
                }

                // empty gadget and reload
                obj.gadget.innerHTML = "";
                obj.gadget.appendChild(fragment);
            })
                .fail(util.errorHandler);
        }
    }
};
```

I'm wondering how to reposition the popup (`$(obj.gadget)`) after I have appended the content.

I tried:

```
 $(obj.gadget).trigger("updatelayout");
```

Or:

```
 $(obj.gadget).popup("reposition", {"y": 0});
```

But they both don't work. Neither does triggering updatelayout on `document`.

**Question**
How can I update the position of a global popup?

Comment: You want to reposition it after it's own and visible?

Comment: would that help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19638417/1771795

Comment: Hey Omar, I would prefer to position it correctly before it is shown, but loading a file in my `getAttachment` handler "takes too long" so JQM is already finished, while I'm still waiting for my Ajax response. So I need to reposition the visible popup.

Comment: Nope, link does not help. I tried all variants with `x`, `y` and `positionTo`. If I log inside JQM, the `reposition` method gets called, which calls internal `_reposition` but in there my method call is swallowed. Maybe a bug... need to check more

Comment: it could be a bug because the code in link works only on 1.3.2 not lower.

Comment: hm. I'm using latest, so maybe regression. I guess it could also be a problem, that the popup is global and not within a page. Strangely enough resizing the browser correctly moves the browser to the coordinates of my previous call... :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42943/discussion-between-omar-and-frequent)

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind it to `popupafteropen`.

```
$(".selector").on("popupafteropen", function () {
    $(this).popup("reposition", {
        "positionTo": "window",
        // or
        x: 100,
        y: 200
    });
});
```

> [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/d8R42/)