# Position jQuery Mobile popup allways 20 pixels below top position of visible area

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, popup, widget, positioning

I´m working on a tool only for tablets (Android, iPad) based on Cordova and jQuery Mobile (1.4.5). In the first phase of this tool, many of the users who have to work with it were asking for some more comfort regarding the behavior of the form popups.

The problem was:

As a user came to one section, I provided him with a collapsible-set, consisting of sub-sections. In this sub-sections, the user gets data-grids with Add, Edit and Delete buttons next to each data-set.
So, as the user tapped on Edit button (or Add), I opened up a popup with the necessary form and form-elements to edit this data-set or add new data to the database. But in many of the upcoming popups the amount of the form-elements is as high, so the popup appears higher or even much higher then the collapsible-set (including the data grid) behind the modal popup is.

The popup of jQuery Mobile is centered by default and even if I positionTo origin and pass x and y coordinates to it, the library/widget wants to position the popup to this coordinates by the center point, rather then the upper left corner.
Users always had to scroll around to come to the start point of the form and after submitting the form, they had to scroll up again to where they tapped on the button to open the popup.

Now I tried to do everything I could imagine, to force the popups top position to 20 pixels below the top position of the visible area on the tablet, regardless of where I am, when tapping on any Edit or Add button.
I was playing around with offset() (window.pageYOffset), etc. and set the position of the popup by:

```
popup2open.popup('open').css({'top':popupTopValue+'px','left':popupLeftValue+'px'});
```

In fact, the popup is positioned to exactly where I want it, if the top offset is between 0 and 100. On all values above 100, the top position of the popup increases by absolutely incomprehensible value. The only consistent fact is, that the more I scroll down before I tap on a button, the more this value increases - so it does not in/decrease by random.

(BTW: I found out that I have to set "popupLeftValue" to 0, so the popup is positioned in the center horizontally.)

I just can´t see any regularity on increasing value...

Can anybody give me a hint or a punch to the right direction?

Thank you in advance!

PS: I experimented also with `.css({'position':'[fixed|absolute]','top':popupTopValue+'px','left':popupLeftValue+'px'});` and that worked well. Only to find out one show-stopper: If I set the focus to an input-field inside the form and than closing the virtual keyboard on the tablet, a reposition-event is triggered and by this, the popup is re-positioned massively below the former position (in fact around 300 pixels below and just marginalized to the right border of visual area). The Cancel and Save buttons are even out of scroll-able area.

(some more funny fact, btw.: if I set the focus to the same input-field, than not closing the virtual-keyboard but directly setting the focus to a select element and after this pressing the back button of the tablet to escape the select menu, no reposition-event is triggered...!?)

On 18th of July 2013 Gabriel Schulhof added this line to a feature-request from one user, who asked exactly for what I´m struggling around with:

```
"We are indeed considering adding such a feature..."
```

Comment: if you have a lot of content inside, don't use a popup - use a dialog page

Comment: @deblocker Thank you... You´re right. I just hoped to work around this decision because I already put a lot of time and energy into this direction. But it´s consuming forces... As I hardly closed one door, three others opened up.

Comment: @all I had a look now on the dialog-page documentation and I remembered again, why I decided not to change to dialog-page widget: The popup widget was very flexible regarding 'after...' events, specially on 'popupafterclose' was very useful. But I will go on for that new way, even if I know that it throws me back for at least one week.

Comment: Replace `popupafterclose` with `$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).on( "pagecontainerhide"...` See here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/

Comment: Don't use `.css()` to set new position, use popup widget method. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19638417/1771795